# Horizontal spry menu drop down items display side-by-side in IE9

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, html-lists, spry

My horizontal spry menu is displaying some of the drop down items side-by-side rather than vertically. They are displaying perfectly in Chrome and FF, but my client uses IE.

Here is the website:

http://www.webexplosive.com/pe_new

and here is my spry CSS, if needed:
(NOTE: I am using images for the drop down items, so I modified the CSS accordingly.)

```
        @charset "UTF-8";

/* SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css - version 0.6 - Spry Pre-Release 1.6.1 */

/* Copyright (c) 2006. Adobe Systems Incorporated. All rights reserved. */

/*******************************************************************************

 LAYOUT INFORMATION: describes box model, positioning, z-order

 *******************************************************************************/

/* The outermost container of the Menu Bar, an auto width box with no margin or padding */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    cursor: default;
    width: auto;
}
/* Set the active Menu Bar with this class, currently setting z-index to accomodate IE rendering bug: http://therealcrisp.xs4all.nl/meuk/IE-zindexbug.html */
ul.MenuBarActive
{
    z-index: 1000;
}
/* Menu item containers, position children relative to this container and are a fixed width */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal li
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
}
/* Submenus should appear below their parent (top: 0) with a higher z-index, but they are initially off the left side of the screen (-1000em) */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    z-index: 1020;
    cursor: default;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1000em;
}
/* Submenu that is showing with class designation MenuBarSubmenuVisible, we set left to auto so it comes onto the screen below its parent menu item */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul.MenuBarSubmenuVisible
{
    left: auto;
}
/* Menu item containers are same fixed width as parent */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul li
{
    width: auto;
}
/* Submenus should appear slightly overlapping to the right (95%) and up (-5%) */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul ul
{
    position: absolute;
    margin: -5% 0 0 95%;
}
/* Submenu that is showing with class designation MenuBarSubmenuVisible, we set left to 0 so it comes onto the screen */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul.MenuBarSubmenuVisible ul.MenuBarSubmenuVisible
{
    left: auto;
    top: 0;
}

/*******************************************************************************

 DESIGN INFORMATION: describes color scheme, borders, fonts

 *******************************************************************************/

/* Submenu containers have borders on all sides */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul
{
    border: 1px thin solid #CCC;
}
/* Menu items are a light gray block with padding and no text decoration */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal a
{
    display: block;
    background-color: #612972;
    padding: 0.0em 0.0em;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px thin solid #CCC;
}
/* Menu items that have mouse over or focus have a blue background and white text */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal a:hover, ul.MenuBarHorizontal a:focus
{
    background-color: #804a92;
    color: #000;
}
/* Menu items that are open with submenus are set to MenuBarItemHover with a blue background and white text */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarItemHover, ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarItemSubmenuHover, ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarSubmenuVisible
{
    background-color: none;
    color: none;
}

/*******************************************************************************

 SUBMENU INDICATION: styles if there is a submenu under a given menu item

 *******************************************************************************/

/* Menu items that have a submenu have the class designation MenuBarItemSubmenu and are set to use a background image positioned on the far left (95%) and centered vertically (50%) */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarItemSubmenu
{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 95% 50%;
}
/* Menu items that have a submenu have the class designation MenuBarItemSubmenu and are set to use a background image positioned on the far left (95%) and centered vertically (50%) */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul a.MenuBarItemSubmenu
{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 95% 50%;
}
/* Menu items that are open with submenus have the class designation MenuBarItemSubmenuHover and are set to use a "hover" background image positioned on the far left (95%) and centered vertically (50%) */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarItemSubmenuHover
{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 95% 50%;
}
/* Menu items that are open with submenus have the class designation MenuBarItemSubmenuHover and are set to use a "hover" background image positioned on the far left (95%) and centered vertically (50%) */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul a.MenuBarItemSubmenuHover
{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 95% 50%;
}

/*******************************************************************************

 BROWSER HACKS: the hacks below should not be changed unless you are an expert

 *******************************************************************************/

/* HACK FOR IE: to make sure the sub menus show above form controls, we underlay each submenu with an iframe */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal iframe
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1010;
    filter:alpha(opacity:0.1);
}
/* HACK FOR IE: to stabilize appearance of menu items; the slash in float is to keep IE 5.0 from parsing */
@media screen, projection
{
    ul.MenuBarHorizontal li.MenuBarItemIE
    {
        display: inline;
        f\loat: left;
        background: transparent;
    }
}
```